# Replacing HTML elements using PHP output buffer very slow

Tags: php, html, buffer

Good afternoon,

I'm using PHP's output buffer to search and incrementally replace HTML tags in an HTML document. My function:

```
function fonorpl($buffer) { 
    $count = 1;
    $fonorep = preg_replace_callback(
        '/<span class="fn">(.*?)<\/span>/',
        function($m) use (&$count) {
            $inkr = $count++;
            $fonotext = '<span class="fonohlf" id="fna'.$inkr.'"><a name="fna'.$inkr.'" href="#fn'.$inkr.'">'.$inkr.'</a>';
            return $fonotext;
        }, 
        $buffer);
    return $fonorep;
}

ob_start("fonorpl");
```

The function is included in the first line of the document and basically looks for `<span class="fn">...</span>` elements and replaces them with incrementally with a number. This number links to a list of all elements on the bottom of the page, which is created by another function (which is not the cause of my problem and therefore is not further mentioned here).

When using this function on a page with a large amount of text (roughly 377,000 characters) and about 380 KB file size, it takes up to 15 seconds until the page is fully loaded. On other pages, which consist of more then 1,000,000 characters and have sizes > 1000 KB, page loading is finished below 1 sec.

I'm just wondering whether this is an issue with ob_buffer and the large amount of text or the preg_replace_callback function I use.

I tried to delete some (larger) text passages to rule out any connections to that, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I also deleted the PHP includes within the document, but this has no effect, too. 
I'm wondering if anyone here as suggestions for me on this matter?

Comment: Why not correct the code that creates the bad html rather than re-process it

Comment: @RiggsFolley: Because I don't want to change all ~ 500 footnotes by hand when I add or delete some at the beginning of the page. Therefore, I want the numbering to be done automatically serverside by PHP.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off with a mass file editing script that would fix those footnotes once and for all.

Comment: @El_Vanja: The footnotes don't need to be fixed. They are included while typing the text, like <span class="fn">blahblah</span>. I'm just replacing the "blahblah" part with a number. The "blahblah" part, which ist the actual footnote text, is displayed in a table at the bottom of the page with the corresponding number in the text. This is - as far as I know - basically the same principle which is used by Latex.

Comment: Ah, so this includes an editor of some kind? Sorry, I misunderstood the purpose. Is the text stored with the html? How is it loaded before you start replacing? There may be a better way around this.

Comment: @El_Vanja: No, there is no editor involved, I just mentioned Latex as an example of the search-and-replace principle (my mistake). I'm typing the text with Notepad++ as HTML text. The text is not loaded from a database or created dynamically or whatsoever. I just want to replace the desired HTML parts within my HTML text prior to loading the page. The procedure would be something like this: user clicks on link to test.php -> test.php is called from the server -> before text of test.php is displayed to the user, all desired HTML parts should be replaced -> "clean" text is displayed to the user.